# Search log can't trace records of Drupal 7 views search terms?

Tags: drupal, search, view

I am using the module - [search log](http://drupal.org/project/search_log), it applied to default search block very well, i.e. /search/node/keyword.

However, when I am using Search terms filter(and exposed to user) in Views. It can't trace anything. How can I work with it?? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can't. A view receives a set of results from the database and then an exposed filter allows you to filter those results.